# antd table actions and onrow function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, antd, feathersjs

While clicking actions in antd table onRow click action is also initiated. How can i solve these problem

```
key = (selectedRowKeys) => {
console.log('selected values', selectedRowKeys);a
   }
action = () => {
console.log('received in actions')
}
```

Table code:

```
<Table
   onRowClick={this.key}
   loading={this.state.loading}
   dataSource={data}
   bordered="true"
>
<Column
 title="ID"
 dataIndex="id"
 key="id"
 width="100"
 zIndex="-1"
/>
<Column
 title="Action"
 key="action"
 width="200"
 render={(text, record) => (
   <span style={{ zIndex: '-1' }}>

     <a href="javascript:;" onClickCapture={this.action}>ACTION</a>
   </span>
 )}
/>
</Table>
```

while clicking the actions in the table the onclick function is also initiated, how to solve this im new to reactjs

Comment: Try using `e.stopPropogation()`. It really depends on which event gets called first. Another issue is that you are using a link, rather than a button. Consider using antd's `<Button type="link">`

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic case of event bubbling.

Try stopping the event propagation in the following way:

```js
action = (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('received in actions');
}
```

This should capture the event and stop it from propagating to the parent event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Table 
      loading={this.state.loading}
      dataSource={data}
      bordered="true"
      onRow={(r) => ({
         onClick: () => console.log(r.key),
      })}
 />
```